# Issues in Listing files in linux

Tags: linux, rhel-5

I want to list all the files present in a directory except for today's file. Suppose today is 19th Sep, i want to list all the files in the directory except for 19th Sep.

Comment: Also, for what purpose?  Eg would sorting the listing to easily weed out the new files before resorting them in alpha order do the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `find` command that ahve dedicated options (cf [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find)):

> -amin n  : File was last accessed n minutes ago.
>
> -atime n : File was last accessed n*24 hours ago. When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least two days ago.
>
> -cmin n  : File was last changed n minutes ago.
>
> -ctime n : File's status was last changed n*24 hours ago. See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file status change times.
>
> -mmin n  : File's data was last modified n minutes ago.
>
> -mtime n : File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago. See the comments for -atime to understand how rounding affects the interpretation of file modification times.

So you can execute the following command, for example:

```
find $MYDIR -ctime +1
```